# In which database table are blocks from the Sonata Block Bundle stored by default?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I could have sworn I remembered there being a `blocks` table, but I appear to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Block info is stored in the `page__block` table. Specifically, the majority of the information will be stored in a JSON string in the column `settings`.